# Como remover o ponto de interrogação "?" no final da URL de uma requisição?

Tags: html, url, http-request, button

Estou utilizando um `form` para disparar uma requisição `GET` para uma endpoint meu sendo que tenho que usar um `<button>` ao invés da tag `<a>` para links porquê o estilo CSS foi feito apenas para a tag `<button>`.

Veja:

```
<form action="/troca" method="get">
 <button class="v-btn v-bg-dark">NOVA TROCA</button>
</form>
```

No entanto, sempre que clico no botão ele dispara a URL e coloca um ponto de interrogação "?" no final da URL, assim:

```
http://localhost:1234/troca?
```

Portanto, eu gostaria de saber como remover este ponto de interrogação da URL deixando ela assim:

```
http://localhost:1234/troca
```

Comment: Mas como você esta submetendo sendo que o botão não é "submit"?

Comment: Troca o method por "post".

Comment: @Sam o post vai acessar outro endpoint o get eh p obter o formulário.

Comment: Mas se tá indo só uma interrogação no final da URL, não tá enviando nada.

Comment: @WictorChaves o comportamento padrão já é o submit de uma [olhada](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element).

Comment: @Sam isso msm, eh so para obter um recurso, mas gostaria que fosse sem a interrogação porque não passo nenhum parâmetro de busca.

Comment: @gato, engraçado, no google chrome teve este comportamento, mas no firefox não funcionou

Comment: Acredito que há um problema de semântica, pois está fazendo um link desfarçado, não da pra simplesmente colocar o botão dentro da tag `<a>`?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam obrigado coloquei o <button> na tag <a> e o estilo manteve também e removeu o `?`.

Comment: @gato, não use o formulário. Use um link direto para a página de troca.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comentaram, mas ninguém respondeu.

Você está utilizando um formulário para criar a navegação entre páginas. Quando você submete um formulário GET, espera-se que você envie parâmetros para gerar uma consulta que definirá o resultado. Por exemplo, um campo de busca no site enviará o parâmetro `?q=Termo` para fazer a pesquisa com base no termo. Seu formulário não possui campos, então não há parâmetros para enviar à outra página e, portanto, a *query string* ficará vazia, mas haverá a presença do `?` pois é uma requisição gerada a partir de uma submissão GET de um formulário.

Mas como comentado, você tentou criar âncoras entre páginas com um formulário. Âncoras são criadas com... bom, âncoras. E no HTML, âncoras são `<a>`. Regra mais básica é: se é navegação, utilize âncoras; se é uma ação interna da página utilize botões.

*Ah, mas eu quero que tenha a aparência de um botão...*

Então defina no seu CSS para que sua âncora se pareça com um botão. CSS é exatamente para isso.

```css
.v-btn {
  background-color: #f8f9fa;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 8px 17px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 10pt;
  letter-spacing: .1rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  height: auto !important;
  -webkit-transition: .3s color, .3s background-color;
  -o-transition: .3s color, .3s background-color;
  transition: .3s color, .3s background-color;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10; }

.v-btn:hover, .v-btn:focus, .v-btn.v-active {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 11; }

.v-btn:disabled {
  cursor: default;
  opacity: .4; }

.v-btn, .v-btn-group {
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
          border-radius: 4px;
  color: #bbb; }
  
/* Hover */
.v-btn.v-bg-primary:hover,
.v-btn.v-bg-primary:focus,
.v-btn.v-bg-primary.v-active,
.v-btn-group.v-bg-primary > .v-btn:hover,
.v-btn-group.v-bg-primary > .v-btn:focus,
.v-btn-group.v-bg-primary > .v-btn.v-active {
  background-color: #025ab9; }
  
.v-bg-primary {
  background-color: #007bff;
  color: #fff; }
```

```html
<link href="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brcontainer/victory.css/master/dist/victory.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a class="v-btn v-bg-primary">Pressione-me!</a>
```

> Código CSS retirado do [arquivo fonte](https://github.com/victory-css/victory.css/blob/master/dist/victory.css) presente no [repositório oficial](https://github.com/victory-css/victory.css).